# In Python, Downloading Png and Jpg images

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

I am writing a script to download images from a certain website. The website contains `jpg` and `png` images.

I was expecting the code to run normally. But the `png` images are taking a while to download (very slow) while the `jpg` images are quick.

```
img_data = requests.get(image_url, headers=headers).content
imagename = ''
if image_url.endswith('.jpg'):
    imagename = str(product) + str(f"{imagevalue:03d}") + '.jpg'
elif image_url.endswith('.png'):
    imagename = str(product) + str(f"{imagevalue:03d}") + '.png'
with open(imagename, 'wb') as file:
    file.write(img_data)
```

This is the code, working but slowly. Am I Missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a problem with your code, rather `.png` files are much larger than `.jpg` files.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't check the sizes of the png files.